# how to get the src of image and show the image?

Tags: javascript

hello guys i want to know how to get the src of image we paste like this : [image: this is the url..but that can be change]

and after show the image in base of the url but the image should be circle like this :

[image: circle image]

like this in center in a url and in the left image : [image]

i have some css :

```
`#preview-img-area {
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    margin: 10px auto auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: #222 !important;
}
#preview-img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    border-color: #222 !important;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background: #222 !important;
}
.arrow-left {
    border-right: 10px solid #000;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    left: 0;
    top: 55px;
}
.nav2 {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.arrow-left, .arrow-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 50%;
}
.arrow-right {
    border-left: 10px solid #000;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    right: 0;
    top: 55px;
}
```

Comment: It really isn't clear what you're trying to do?  You display an image URL by creating an `<img>` tag, setting the `.src` property on the image object and then inserting it into your page.  The browser will handle downloading the image and displaying it.

Comment: i have updated the post look it now . i dont understood and all what u said

Comment: Still do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: oh so i m asking for preview image ..when ipaste the url in the tab how to preview the image of the url i posted check the third pic ..in the center is the url of the pic and in the left the preview of that url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Javascript to set the `.src` property of an `<img>` tag to the desired image URL, then the browser will display that image.

Here's a simple example:

```js
document.getElementById("imageURL").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    document.getElementById("imagePreview").src = this.value;
})
```

```html
Paste Image URL Here: <input id="imageURL"><br><br>
<img id="imagePreview" height="200">
```

Any formatting or positioning of the image has to obviously be done by your markup or CSS.  This shows you to display the image.

Comment: can i ask u 1 more question ..there is way to keep the image url bacause when i reload the page need to repaste the url to show the image

Comment: @Harryzingh - That's really the subject for another question.  User added content does not naturally survive a page reload.  If you want it to, then you have to store the data somewhere (cookie, local storage, on the server) and then when your page loads, it has to look for previously saved content and put that in the page.  If you need further help with that, first do a search here on stack overflow on how to do that and then if you don't find anything here or on Google, ask a new question.

Comment: hei sorry for disturbing but how can i store that in local storage?

Comment: @Harryzingh - As I said, that's a subject for another question.  Feel free to ask another question if your Google research doesn't find the answer.